# JavaScript contenteditable

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I am creating a HTML rich text editor and I would like to use the contenteditable attribute on a div. I have a list of divs inside a div called editor. When the user hits enter I prevent the default action. I then insert a new div after the current div. The only problem is I cannot focus on the new div. Does anyone know how to do this?

The HTML

```
<body>
        <div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
            <div id="1" contenteditable="ture" class="line" style="height: 20px; background-color: #a0f;"></div>
            <div contenteditable="ture" class="line" style="height: 20px; background-color: #abf;"></div>
            <div contenteditable="ture" class="line" style="height: 20px; background-color: #a9f;"></div>
            <div contenteditable="ture" class="line" style="height: 20px; background-color: #aff;"></div>
            <div contenteditable="ture" class="line" style="height: 20px; background-color: #aaf;"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

The JavaScript

```
 $(function(){

        var thisLine;

        $("#editor").bind("keydown", function(event){
            if(event.keyCode == 13){
                event.preventDefault(); 
                var newLine = $("<div tabindex=\"-1\" contenteditable=\"ture\" id=\"2\"class=\"line\" style=\"height: 20px; background-color: #aff;\"></div>");
                        newLine.insertAfter(thisLine);
                        $("#2").focus();
                    }
                })

                $(".line").bind("click", function(){
                    thisLine = $(this);
                })

            });
```

Comment: Also, in your example, all div's inside editor have `contenteditable="ture"` .. this should say TRUE :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
newLine.insertAfter(thisLine).focus();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/7xEXt/

Comment: So that doesn't work when the newly inserted div is inside of a parent div.

Answer (score 0):

Get the selection, and add a new collapsed range to it. See `moveCaretToStartOf` method in the example

```js
function moveCaretToStartOf(element) {
  var selection = document.getSelection();
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.setStart(element, 0);
  selection.addRange(range)
}

document.querySelector('div').focus();
window.setTimeout(function () {
 moveCaretToStartOf(document.querySelectorAll('p')[1])
}, 1000);
```

```html
<blockquote>
  Cursor will be placed into the second paragraph after 1 second
</blockquote>
<div contenteditable="true">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel laboriosam nobis nam tempore sint adipisci, ullam perspiciatis placeat aliquid dolorem. Aliquid nisi, dicta sunt dolor qui voluptatem perferendis veniam ad!</p>
  <p><br></p>
</div>
```